# I get weird shapes when I extrude and scale a mesh

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, extrude, scale

I am currently doing the doughnut tutorial, part 6, from [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izqZe8s_Jmw), and I am now supposed to model a plate. Unfortunately whenever I copy the instructions, I get these really weird shapes and my plate looks messed up.

I extrude and scale it but it just doesn't come out right.

[image]
created the circle

[image]
extruded

[image]
scaled it

Comment: Turn off Proportional Fall-off by pressing O before extruding and scaling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [Proportional Edit](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html#edit-mode) with the "random" falloff setting. To turn it off, click on the blue button in this menu and select "disable":

[image]

or press <kbd>O</kbd> while in Edit mode